# Store file at the time of apk installation

Tags: android, apk

Is it possible to  store a file in data at the time of app installation in android?I want to do this because to prevent the apk sharing.Once the app installed my file should store in data and will check this file when app runs first time.If that file ispresent then legal else illegal.

I work around but didnt got anything plss help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for an application to run code as a result of itself being installed.

Some people may mistakenly tell you about broadcast receivers for installation broadcasts, but those are not supposed to notify the application which itself is being installed.

Comment: Ultimately you cannot.  And without at least occasional internet access, most of the present crop of annoyance-level protection methods such as market licensing checks won't even begin to work.